# jupyter notebook fail to import gdal while normal terminal python can

Tags: python, jupyter, gdal

I got gdal installed successfully on my mac big sur.
the following command runs fine on my terminal

```sh
which python3
# /usr/local/bin/python3
python3
```

then I can import gdal in python console

```py
from osgeo import gdal
```

[image]

and then I opened vscode and Jupyter notebook, Jupyter told me I'm using `/usr/local/bin/python3` as the kernel, but when i execute in Jupyter

```py
from osgeo import gdal
```

it fails with an importerror

ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/osgeo/_gdal.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _GEOSArea
Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/libspatialite/lib/libspatialite.7.dylib
Expected in: flat namespace
in /usr/local/opt/libspatialite/lib/libspatialite.7.dylib

also, I always start Jupyter notebook via right click -> run current file in interactive Window. It gives me an import error immediately, but if I restart the kernel and type the following in interactive mode

```py
from osgeo import gdal
```

It works fine, and it confuses me a lot.

## edit

the developer of georasters, ozak asked this question on github

https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/214

and the developer of fiona answered it.

https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/issues/92

long story short. Fiona package is not compatible with osgeo.*

Comment: I suggest using anaconda or miniconda python, then install gdal into a new conda environment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Robert. I found that this weird behavior is a result of import orders. When I import geopandas first, this error occurs, while if I import gdal first, both package works fine... I have no idea how this happens...

Comment: Does it work when you run `jupyter-lab .` on the command-line?  The reason I ask is that it appears your python path is wonky.  You could have an issue where the GUI initializes using a different set of path variables than when you restart the kernel.  Perhaps there is a Jupyter config file setting that's wrong...
https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html

Comment: hi msmith, I tried `jupyter-lab .` on the command-line, it makes no difference. I think the problem consist when using fiona(geopandas and so on) and gdal together. I also edit the problem and paste some link related to this problem. It's not a jupyter's problem, just problem between python packages